# 14.04 LTS openstack install fails on multi-node installations

Tags: juju, cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Fresh install on 8 nodes, deployed using MAAS.

Running `sudo openstack-install` fails with the following error message;

```
DEBUG • 01-04 21:33:13 [LINE:54, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 69, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

Also tried installing with latest experimental;

```
sudo openstack-install --extra-ppa ppa:cloud-installer/experimental
```

But fails with the same issue;

```
DEBUG • 01-04 22:04:23 [LINE:54, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 69, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 144, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

What's failing is the juju bootstrap step. You should try that outside of the cloud installer to see if you can get more information.

Point juju at your MAAS environment and try to bootstrap there. If a plain `juju bootstrap` doesn't yield any clues, try `juju bootstrap --debug`.

Also make sure that you have nodes in the ready state in MAAS.